# Is there deb packages that display license agreement?

Tags: package-management, deb, debconf

Could you please list some deb packages that show license agreement and ask to accept it?
I would like to learn their internals.

Comment: license agreement of what exactly?

Comment: @Alvar, any End User License Agreement that is required to be accepted to be able to install a package.

Comment: only time I've done that is when I installed mysql server. a lot of software on Ubuntu is released as open for anyone to modify, so you don't see a lot of license agreements...

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, the `msttcorefonts` package asks to accept an EULA.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to sell commercial software through the software center, I think they provide a mechanism for license presentation and acceptance (although someone familiar with the process might be able to correct me there).

Otherwise, if you intend to distribute something on a free software basis, clickwrap licenses are a *Bad Idea*. For instance, they make it difficult to install the package in an automated fashion (how can the license be accepted then?), and (as far as I know) it remains unclear whether a clickwrap license in practice carries any more force than one just included in the package. Any sort of restrictive license is also likely to reduce the dissemination of your software, as any uncertainty about rights will lead to distributions and mirrors not carrying it, or relegating it to secondary or non-default package collections.

The [Debian Free Software Guidelines](http://www.debian.org/social_contract.html) ([FAQ](http://people.debian.org/~bap/dfsg-faq.html)) are the guidelines which the Debian project follows for accepting software into their archive. It should be noted that Ubuntu, while Debian-derived, follows a generally more-flexible policy on software freedom than Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for copyright files in deb packages here: [Machine-readable debian/copyright file](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/)

As far as I am concerned, this is from 2012, so a very young development. Not much packages include a machine readable licence by now, and I am not sure how apt managers handle it.

Get more info about this issue on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884753/license-info-of-a-deb-package

My personal intention says, most "Accept Licence" Dialogs are made by the vendors themselfs.

P.S: That a licence needs to be accepted by the user to be valid or that an accepted licence is automatically valid is a misunderstanding. You need to inform the user about the licence, but that does not necessarily mean that you need a Dialog with "Accept" - "Decline".

Comment: copyright-format 1.0 is only meant as a way of defining the copyright and licensing info per file in a project; it has no concept of or facility for user acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

No software in Ubuntu or Debian proper (that is, free software) ought to ask the user to accept any license on install. But there are debs of non-free packages as well, some of which do so. Another poster mentioned `msttcorefonts`; some others (if I remember right) are `flashplugin-nonfree` and `sun-java6-jdk` (recently removed from Debian and Ubuntu due to license changes).

The larger answer that you probably want, though, is that the Right Way to do this is by using [Debconf](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html).